# Handling divide zero when have to use aggregation function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the query where select records by a formula contains division, here is my query:

```
SELECT
    Id AS [ID]
    IIF(max(c.Capacity) = 0, 0.0,
                   max(TRY_CONVERT(float, f.Value) /
                       TRY_CONVERT(float, c.Capacity))) AS [Value],
FROM Form f 
LEFT JOIN Control c 
ON f.ID = c.FormID
GROUP BY 
    f.Id
```

My error is:

> Divide by zero error encountered

The problem is I have to use `Group By` and it requires `max()` in `IIF()` which can not filter out `Capacity = 0`. Anyone have ideas how to fix this?

Comment: It depends what you're actually trying to calculate. Replacing zeros will NULLs is one approach. In your specific case, you should just put a WHERE clause on it (but that does not guarantee you won't get the error)

Comment: I see you have a left join so `where` won't cut it. Instead try `ON f.ID = c.FormID AND c.Capacity <> 0` in your join clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use `NULLIF`

```
SELECT
    Id AS [ID]
    IIF(max(c.Capacity) = 0, 0.0,
            max(TRY_CONVERT(float, f.Value) /
                    NULLIF(c.Capacity, 0)) AS [Value],
FROM Form f 
LEFT JOIN Control c 
ON f.ID = c.FormID
GROUP BY 
    f.Id
```

Comment: thank you! But I wonder Does divide to null will slow the query than to number? Do you have any idea? @zealous

Comment: @NLeeT it won't slow the query performance as far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `capacity` is never negative and the values are numbers of some sort, you can simplify the logic to:

```
COALESCE(MAX(f.Value * 1.0 / NULLIF(c.capacity, 0)), 0) as [Value]
```

If the values are already numbers and you are converting just to avoid division by `0`, the `try_convert()` is not wrong, but it is misleading.  `try_convert()` suggests that the conversion might fail.